# AWS:EC2 - php files are not working

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

When I load my website, no pages are loading and looking into Apache logs, i see the following errors

```
[Thu Jun 25 09:42:59.279803 2015] [:error] [pid 31196] PHP Warning:  include_once(/var/www/htdocs/inc/inc/util/sessionmanager.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/htdocs/inc/util/inag.php on line 13
[Thu Jun 25 09:42:59.279854 2015] [:error] [pid 31196] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/var/www/htdocs/inc/inc/util/sessionmanager.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/htdocs/inc/util/inag.php on line 13
[Thu Jun 25 09:42:59.279875 2015] [:error] [pid 31196] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/htdocs/inc/inc/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/htdocs/inc/util/inag.php on line 14
[Thu Jun 25 09:42:59.279884 2015] [:error] [pid 31196] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/htdocs/inc/inc/config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/htdocs/inc/util/inag.php on line 14
```

I have changed the root directory from /var/www/html to /var/www/htdocs for which I did the following changes in https.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html" => "/var/www/htdocs"
```

And it worked

I also tried to change

```
<Directory "/var/www">
  AllowOverride None
  # Allow open access:
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory "/var/www">
  AllowOverride All
  # Allow open access:
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

but it did not work for the purpose (loading index.php for pretty url).

Any idea how to get the php files loading properly?

Comment: Does Apache have permission to open those files?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Never mind, I should've read the errors properly first. `No such file or directory` is the error you need to fix. There's a double `inc/inc` in the path of the file it's searching for so your `include`/`require` statements probably need to look a directory higher